# Mongoose subdocument validation based on required

Tags: node.js, mongoose

TL;DR: how to make custom-type field required in one case (and run validations for subdocument) and not required in other case (without validation for subdocument)?

I have an `adress` schema and models who using this schema (code below).
In one case it is required and in other case it is not. So how to correctly validate an `address`? All fields except 'apartment' should be required if this field is required and could be empty or valid (for index case) if it's not required.

Is there some options to pass some options to the child schema for this cases or should I make custom validator in each model?

```
// adress SCHEMA
module.exports = mongoose.Schema({
  town: String,
  index: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: function (v) {
        return /^\d+$/.test(v)
      },
      message: 'Invalid index'
    }
  },
  district: String,
  street: String,
  house: String,
  apartment: String
})

// user.js
const Address = require('./address')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  address: {
    type: Address,
    required: true // Adress required here
  }
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema)

// other.js
const Address = require('./address')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const otherSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  address: Address // but not here
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Other', otherSchema)
```

Answer (score 0):

to make all fields except apartment required, you just use the required attribute, same way you did with address:

```
town: {type: String, required: true},
district: {type: String, required: true},
street: {type: String, required: true},
house: {type: String, required: true},
apartment: String
```

If one of the required fields is left empty, there will be an error when using the create method, the error can be handled to return/keep the user to/on the form page and display an error message to inform them they need to fill the required fields

As for validation, you can check [this page](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html) of the official mongoose docs to see if the Built-In Validators are enough for your purposes or if you do need to use Custom Validators on some of your fields.

Comment: I know how to make field required. I've asked how to make it NOT required in second case when `adress: {type: Adress}` is not required? In this case it still throwing an error based on child schema required rule.

Comment: @Iworb doesn't setting ` adress: {type: Adress, required: false}` work ?